# Automate login + download from a web page

Tags: azure, google-chrome, web, imacros

I want to automate this task:

1. Login to a weg page (user + password)
2. Select a certain download form
3. Fill the form
4. Download a report file

So far, I have automated this task with **iMacros** for Chrome.
Now I want to run it on a server, ideally in **Azure** (Web API or something else). Do you see a chance to automate this?

Answer (score 0):

Download Selenium Webdrivers from chrome extensions and use it. It is a simple click and recording type interface.

- Also It will allow you to Save your scripts in Python,Java, etc.. type Codes

Link : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd